# cx_Freeze 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, pygame, executable, cx-freeze, file-type

I'm trying to turn a pygame file into a .exe, and I'm using cx_Freeze to do it

however, when I type `py setup.py build` into the console, it responds:

```
PS C:\Python34> py setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("CattwalkV3C.py")]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 24, in __init__
    distutils.dist.Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 236, in __init__
    for (opt, val) in cmd_options.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I've seen a couple other questions with this problem, but they both just say that certain items are over-encapsulated. Here is my code:

```
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import *

files = ["BLUE CALLISTO.png", "RED CALLISTO.png", "BLUE LUNA.png",
"RED LUNA.png", "BLUE DEIMOS.png", "RED DEIMOS.png"
"BLUE GANYMEDE.png", "RED GANYMEDE.png", "BLUE IO.png",
"RED IO.png", "BLUE EUROPA.png", "RED EUROPA.png",
"BLUE TITAN.png", "RED TITAN.png", "RED SOL.png",
"BLUE SOL.png", "CattwalkBoard.png", "STYX.png"
"blue turn.png", "red turn.png", "LongLine.png",
"ShortLine.png", "PlaceHolder.png"]

includeThese = ["pygame", "pickle", "os", "random", "time", "math", 
"socket"]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "CattwalkV3C",
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages": includeThese},
                                    "include_files": files},

    executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("CattwalkV3C.py")]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your format is kind of messed up, try using this one:

```
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import *

files = ["BLUE CALLISTO.png", "RED CALLISTO.png", "BLUE LUNA.png",
"RED LUNA.png", "BLUE DEIMOS.png", "RED DEIMOS.png"
"BLUE GANYMEDE.png", "RED GANYMEDE.png", "BLUE IO.png",
"RED IO.png", "BLUE EUROPA.png", "RED EUROPA.png",
"BLUE TITAN.png", "RED TITAN.png", "RED SOL.png",
"BLUE SOL.png", "CattwalkBoard.png", "STYX.png"
"blue turn.png", "red turn.png", "LongLine.png",
"ShortLine.png", "PlaceHolder.png"]
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("CattwalkV3C.py")]
includeThese = ["pygame", "pickle", "os", "random", "time", "math", 
"socket"]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "CattwalkV3C",
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages": includeThese,
                            "include_files": includeThese 
                            },
               })
```